# Rails belongs_to triggered when call save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, eager-loading

Assume I have User 1-n with UserNotification

The problem is I dont know why everytime I try to save UserNotification, rails auto SELECT the user of that UserNotification triggered n + 1 problem

for example

```
UserNotification.where(id: [1,2,3]).update(updated_at: Time.current)
```

will generate these SQL

```
 UserNotification Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `user_notifications`.* FROM `user_notifications` WHERE `user_notifications`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (3, 1)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4
```

the UserNotification model is simple belongs_to :user

I've already read the update source code but still have no clue

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is Rails 5 makes belongs to required by default. Then everytime a record gets updated it loads the association to verify its presence. What you can do (I don't know how clean this is but until Rails fixes it I guess it's fine), is add a custom validation to validate the belongs to presence, so that it only runs when creating or changing the associated record.

```
belongs_to :my_association, optional: true
validate :my_association, presence: true, if: :needs_validate_my_association_presence?

def needs_validate_my_association_presence?
   new_record? || my_association_id_changed?
end
```

In your case `my_association` would be `user`